# Simulations for uniform limit theorems

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo

When it comes to simulations, I am unfortunately new: How can I verify the performance of my theoretical result, being a limit theorem of the following type:
$$\text{sup}_{t\in[0,1]} X_{t}^{n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow} Z\,,$$ with $Z$ being a random variable, which distribution is known and $X^{n}_{t}=\alpha_{n} \cdot s\cdot g(W_{t/n}-W_{t/n-1})$, with $s>0$ unknown. $W$ is the Wiener process on the unit interval and $\alpha_{n}$ is a properly rescaling sequence. $g$ is some known, deterministic and smooth function.
How can I perform simulations, which suggest, that my theoretical result is true? Especially the $\text{sup}$ part causes difficulties.
Some hints on appropriate literature would also be nice.
I am interested in the general procedure, handling the sup term.

Comment: It depends on what "$X_t^n$" means and in what form you know these distributions: those are the details we need to answer this question.

Comment: @whuber I have added some additonal remarks.

Comment: I think that there would be no problem without the sup part, since it is basically just necessary to simulate from a normal sample. But the sup term causes some difficulties.

Comment: The calculation of the supremum is straightforward but potentially expensive and subject to error. However, a little more information about $g$ could allow for (a) a more efficient algorithm and (b) control over the error.  In particular, would $g$ be monotonic?